# How run a bash script on nodejs output

Tags: node.js, bash, pipe

I have a nodejs script that produce some output like that (*it scrape website and output url*) :

`process.stdout.write(url)`

And I want my bash to use this url (*basically it just curl the url*) and do some stuff.

I try `node myapp | bash mybash` ==> `Error: write EPIPE`

I try `node myapp | grep 'www'`  ==> I see url spawn

I probably missing something about stdin stdout
For the moment, in my bash I just `echo $1`

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53571637/command-line-arguments-vs-input-whats-the-difference

Comment: Perhaps see also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1504867/pipe-standard-input-and-command-line-arguments-in-bash

Answer (score 1):

Your question is rather unclear, but I guess you are looking for

```sh
node myapp |
while IFS= read -r url; do
    : something with "$url"
done
```

If `mybash` expects a single command-line argument, maybe you want `mybash "$url"` inside the loop; though perhaps in your case you want to instead refactor your script to do the `read` loop instead, or as an option.

Very often [you want to avoid this and write e.g. an Awk script or something instead;](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13762625/bash-while-read-loop-extremely-slow-compared-to-cat-why) but this is how you read from standard input in Bash.

Comment: Sorry for my unclear question, In fact, like in bash when we pipe thing : echo XX | grep XX | awk XX ... I want to be able to do the same with a nodejs code which output something

Comment: But your right, I missunderstood input and line argument

Comment: Ok I was completly looking for read: 
`read foo
echo "You entered '$foo'"`catch the stdout from the nodejs script

Answer (score 0):

I often use this and integrate it with my own tools. It might help you:

```
const { exec } = require('child_process');
exec('shell.sh value', (err, stdout, stderr) => {
  if (err) {
    console.error(err)
  } else {
   console.log(`stdout: ${stdout}`);
   console.log(`stderr: ${stderr}`);
  }
});
```

[Learn more](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/node-js-child-processes-everything-you-need-to-know-e69498fe970a/) about child processes.

Answer (score 0):

The solution that fit for me was :

In nodejs file :
`process.stdout.write(url+' ')`

And in bash file:

`read url_from_node`

`url_list=$( echo $url_from_node |  tr ' ' '\n')`
then process this list...

Then `node myApp | mybash` works

Comment: You should [fix your quoting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10067266/when-to-wrap-quotes-around-a-shell-variable). You can use `echo "${url_from_node// /$'\n'}"` though a better fix is probably to make your `node` program output one URL per line in the first place (again, perhaps, optionally, if you have mysterious but possibly legitimate reasons to prefer an objectively speaking more cumbersome output format by default).