# Passing arrays as command line arguments with xargs

Tags: bash, xargs

I have the following two scripts:

```
#script1.sh:
#!/bin/bash
this_chunk=(1 2 3 4)
printf "%s\n" "${this_chunk[@]}" | ./script2.sh


#script2.sh:
#!/bin/bash
while read -r arr 
do
    echo "--$arr"
done
```

When I execute `script1.sh`, the output is as expected:

```
--1
--2
--3
--4
```

which shows that I was able to pipe the elements of the array `this_chunk` as arguments to `script2.sh`. However, if I change the line calling `script2.sh` to

```
printf "%s\n" "${this_chunk[@]}" | xargs ./script2.sh
```

there is no output. My question is, how to pass the array `this_chunk` using `xargs`, rather than simple piping? The reason is that I will have to deal with large arrays and thus long argument lists which will be a problem with piping.

**Edit:**
Based on the answers and comments, this is the correct way to do it:

```
#script1.sh
#!/bin/bash
this_chunk=(1 2 3 4)
printf "%s\0" "${this_chunk[@]}" | xargs -0 ./script2.sh


#script2.sh
#!/bin/bash
for i in "${@}"; do
    echo $i
done
```

Comment: You seem to misunderstand what `xargs` does. You script ignores arguments. `hus long argument lists which will be a problem with piping.` ? Why would it be a problem? You can definitely pass more via a pipe then via command line arguments.

Comment: `xargs` is working as expected, but script2.sh ignores its arguments. Try adding `echo "Received $# arguments:" "$@"` at the beginning of script2.sh to see them.

Comment: @Botond: You do not _pipe any array_ into another process. You invoke one command (`printf`) by causing the shell to pass the individual array elements as arguments to this command; this command produces on stdout some stream of text, and this stream is then piped into the next process. The receiving process never sees an array, because standard input is an untyped stream of characters; there is no concept of "array" in standard inpjut.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> how to pass the array this_chunk using xargs

Note that `xargs` by default interprets `'` `"` and `\` sequences. To disable the interpretation, either preprocess the data, or better use GNU xargs with `-d '\n'` option. `-d` option is not part of POSIX xargs.

```
printf "%s\n" "${this_chunk[@]}" | xargs -d '\n' ./script2.sh
```

That said, with GNU xargs prefer zero terminated streams, to preserve newlines:

```
printf "%s\0" "${this_chunk[@]}" | xargs -0 ./script2.sh
```

Your script `./script2.sh` ignores command line arguments, and your `xargs` spawns the process with standard input closed. Because the input is closed, `read -r arr` fails, so your scripts does not print anything, as expected. (Note that in POSIX xargs, when the spawned process tries to read from stdin, the result is unspecified.)

Comment: thank you. May I ask you to also explain why the piping worked? Passing via piping is not equivalent to passing by arguments?

Comment: I guess pipe directs input, not arguments.

Comment: `why the piping worked?` Because your scripts reads from standard input with `read`. `Passing via piping is not equivalent to passing by arguments?` Yes, it is definitely not equivalent, these are very different things.

Comment: @Botond For more about the difference between arguments and input, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53571637/command-line-arguments-vs-input-whats-the-difference) and [this one](https://superuser.com/questions/600253/why-is-xargs-necessary/600273).